# SQL Server Automatic Index Changes (A filter on my index is gone)

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I'm using SQL Server 2008

I know that an index on a view will be deleted without prejudice nor warning if you change the view definition. I am wondering if there are any other known similar automatic changes to indexes and if so where can I read about them?

My situation:

- I had a unique non-clustered filtered index on a table.
- The index key columns are the same as the primary key of the table.
- Only one other column is included.
- Today I when things were going slowly, I realized that the filter is now gone.
- One of the primary key column types was recently changed to a different type. So I'm guessing that may have been when the filter removal happened, but I can't find verification of that anywhere.
- If it helps, I could not simply add the filter back because when trying to recreate, 'The new index definition does not match the constraint being enforced by the existing index.'
- Neither can I simply drop the index to recreate it because [apparently](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20168/how-does-sql-server-choose-an-index-key-for-a-foreign-key-reference) SQL Server decided to use the index to enforce foreign key constraints instead of the clustered PK index. I will have to delete foreign key constraints before I do.

All of our devs said that they didn't mess with the index. One of us may be forgetful. Or lying. Or someone may have changed something and not have read very carefully the warning messages. I don't know if this is something that could be automatic so I'm hoping you guys can inform me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess someone is fishing :)
Here's test code which shows that you can't change PK's column data type *without* dropping indexes off first:

```
create table dbo.worker
(
    id int identity not null constraint PK_worker primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null
);

-- Filtered index based in PK's primary index
create nonclustered index ix_worker
on dbo.worker (id)
where id < 3;

-- Try to change PK's column data type...
alter table dbo.worker
    alter column id bigint;
```

SQL Server generates following errors:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1,
>
> Line 8 The index 'ix_worker' is dependent on column 'id'.
>
> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>
> The object 'PK_worker' is dependent on column 'id'.
>
> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>
> The index 'ix_worker' is dependent on column  'id'.
>
> Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 8
>
> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN id failed because one or more objects access this column.